# How to move all video files with mp3 audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, bash

My folder has some video files with mp3 audio and some video files with aac audio. I want to move all files which have mp3 audio to another folder. When I asked my friend, he gave me this script:

**mp3ToAAC.sh**

```
#To convert mp3 audio to AAC
for file in *;
do
    if [ $file == "mp3ToAAC.sh" ]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec aac -vcodec copy ../"$file"
    fi 
done
```

That will convert all video files with audio mp3 to aac. Before using this, I want to move the files which have mp3 audio to another directory. I want to run this script only on those files. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the question has an error. I shall ask the OP to correct it.

The code to move files is:

```
#To move mp3 video to parent
for file in *;
do
    if [ "$file" == "moveMp3.sh" ]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        audioFormat=$(ffprobe -loglevel error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$file")
        if [ -z $audioFormat ]; then
            continue;
        fi
        if [ $audioFormat == "mp3" ]; then
            mv "$file" ../"$file"
        fi
    fi
done
```

The code to convert mp3 can be:

```
#To convert mp3 audio to AAC
for file in *;
do
    if [ $file == "mp3ToAAC.sh" ]; then
        continue;
    fi
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -map 0 -c copy -c:a:0 aac ../"$file"
    fi 
done
```